# lazy load failed in webview of Android

Tags: android, webview, lazy-loading

I faced a big problem to use webview of android to load the url http://www.wenba.ca/question/answer_detail/?question_id=7542&answer_id=15325, which implemented lazy load tip to improve the performance of webview. Each time when access the url, there is whole html content and default picture of all images, but when scroll the page, real picture is not loaded later.

I have captured all request packages, there is no download for js file of lazy load, including (jquery.js and jquery.lazyload.min.js), and also no request for images, but when refresh the url, the second time lazy load works fine, and all images could be shown in the webview.

I have tested the same url in IOS app, it works fine.

I can not find reasons, could give any suggestions?

Comment: Were you able to find out an answer to your problem? I'm facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, just you need specify the continer with scrollbars, the script by default takes a window object, for example if you use jquery mobile, scroll bars are within the main div:

```js
$("img.lazy").lazyload({continer: $(".ui-content")});//main div
```

and use my modified version of lazyload plugin:

```js
/*
 * Lazy Load - jQuery plugin for lazy loading images
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2007-2013 Mika Tuupola
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license:
 *   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *
 * Project home:
 *   http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload
 *
 * Version:  1.9.3
 *
 */

(function($, window, document, undefined) {
    var $window = $(window);
    var iOS = !!navigator.platform && /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.platform);

    $.fn.lazyload = function(options) {
        var elements = this;
        var $container;
        
        var settings = {
            threshold       : 0,
            failure_limit   : 0,
            event           : "scroll",
            effect          : "show",
            container       : window,
            data_attribute  : "original",
            skip_invisible  : true,
            appear          : null,
            load            : null,
            placeholder     : "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsQAAA7EAZUrDhsAAAANSURBVBhXYzh8+PB/AAffA0nNPuCLAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"
        };

        function update() 
        {
            var counter = 0;

            elements.each(function() 
            {
                var $this = $(this);
                if (settings.skip_invisible && !$this.is(":visible")) {
                    return;
                }
                if ($.abovethetop(this, settings) ||
                    $.leftofbegin(this, settings)) {
                        /* Nothing. */
                } else if (!$.belowthefold(this, settings) && !$.rightoffold(this, settings)) {
                        $this.trigger("appear");
                        /* if we found an image we'll load, reset the counter */
                        counter = 0;
                } else {
                    if (++counter > settings.failure_limit) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });

        }

        if(options) 
        {
            /* Maintain BC for a couple of versions. */
            if (undefined !== options.failurelimit) {
                options.failure_limit = options.failurelimit;
                delete options.failurelimit;
            }
            if (undefined !== options.effectspeed) {
                options.effect_speed = options.effectspeed;
                delete options.effectspeed;
            }

            $.extend(settings, options);
        }

        /* Cache container as jQuery as object. */
        $container = (settings.container === undefined || settings.container === window) ? $window : $(settings.container);

        /* Fire one scroll event per scroll. Not one scroll event per image. */
        if (0 === settings.event.indexOf("scroll")) 
        {
            
            if(iOS === true)
            {
                $container.bind(settings.event, function() {

                    return update();
                });
            }
            else//Entra cuando el navegador no es IOS
            {
                $container.bind("scrollstart", function() {

                    return update();
                });
                
                $container.bind("scrollstop", function() {

                    return update();
                });
            }
        }

        this.each(function() {
            var self = this;
            var $self = $(self);

            self.loaded = false;

            /* If no src attribute given use data:uri. */
            if ($self.attr("src") === undefined || $self.attr("src") === false) {
                if ($self.is("img")) {
                    $self.attr("src", settings.placeholder);
                }
            }

            /* When appear is triggered load original image. */
            $self.one("appear", function() {
                if (!this.loaded) {
                    if (settings.appear) {
                        var elements_left = elements.length;
                        settings.appear.call(self, elements_left, settings);
                    }
                    
                    
                    
                    $("<img />")
                        .bind("load", function() {

                            var original = $self.attr("data-" + settings.data_attribute);
                            $self.hide();
                            if ($self.is("img")) {
                                $self.attr("src", original);
                            } else {
                                $self.css("background-image", "url('" + original + "')");
                            }
                            $self[settings.effect](settings.effect_speed);

                            self.loaded = true;

                            /* Remove image from array so it is not looped next time. */
                            var temp = $.grep(elements, function(element) {
                                return !element.loaded;
                            });
                            elements = $(temp);

                            if (settings.load) {
                                var elements_left = elements.length;
                                settings.load.call(self, elements_left, settings);
                            }
                        })
                        .attr("src", $self.attr("data-" + settings.data_attribute));
                }
            });

            /* When wanted event is triggered load original image */
            /* by triggering appear.                              */
            if (0 !== settings.event.indexOf("scroll")) {
                $self.bind(settings.event, function() {
                    if (!self.loaded) {
                        $self.trigger("appear");
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        /* Check if something appears when window is resized. */
        $window.bind("resize", function() {
            update();
        });

        /* With IOS5 force loading images when navigating with back button. */
        /* Non optimal workaround. */
        if ((/(?:iphone|ipod|ipad).*os 5/gi).test(navigator.appVersion)) {
            $window.bind("pageshow", function(event) {
                if (event.originalEvent && event.originalEvent.persisted) {
                    elements.each(function() {
                        $(this).trigger("appear");
                    });
                }
            });
        }

        /* Force initial check if images should appear. */
        $(document).ready(function() {
            update();
        });

        return this;
    };

    /* Convenience methods in jQuery namespace.           */
    /* Use as  $.belowthefold(element, {threshold : 100, container : window}) */

    $.belowthefold = function(element, settings) {
        var fold;

        if (settings.container === undefined || settings.container === window) {
            fold = (window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : $window.height()) + $window.scrollTop();
        } else {
            fold = $(settings.container).offset().top + $(settings.container).height();
        }

        return fold <= $(element).offset().top - settings.threshold;
    };

    $.rightoffold = function(element, settings) {
        var fold;

        if (settings.container === undefined || settings.container === window) {
            fold = $window.width() + $window.scrollLeft();
        } else {
            fold = $(settings.container).offset().left + $(settings.container).width();
        }

        return fold <= $(element).offset().left - settings.threshold;
    };

    $.abovethetop = function(element, settings) {
        var fold;

        if (settings.container === undefined || settings.container === window) {
            fold = $window.scrollTop();
        } else {
            fold = $(settings.container).offset().top;
        }

        return fold >= $(element).offset().top + settings.threshold  + $(element).height();
    };

    $.leftofbegin = function(element, settings) {
        var fold;

        if (settings.container === undefined || settings.container === window) {
            fold = $window.scrollLeft();
        } else {
            fold = $(settings.container).offset().left;
        }

        return fold >= $(element).offset().left + settings.threshold + $(element).width();
    };

    $.inviewport = function(element, settings) {
         return !$.rightoffold(element, settings) && !$.leftofbegin(element, settings) &&
                !$.belowthefold(element, settings) && !$.abovethetop(element, settings);
     };

    /* Custom selectors for your convenience.   */
    /* Use as $("img:below-the-fold").something() or */
    /* $("img").filter(":below-the-fold").something() which is faster */

    $.extend($.expr[":"], {
        "below-the-fold" : function(a) { return $.belowthefold(a, {threshold : 0}); },
        "above-the-top"  : function(a) { return !$.belowthefold(a, {threshold : 0}); },
        "right-of-screen": function(a) { return $.rightoffold(a, {threshold : 0}); },
        "left-of-screen" : function(a) { return !$.rightoffold(a, {threshold : 0}); },
        "in-viewport"    : function(a) { return $.inviewport(a, {threshold : 0}); },
        /* Maintain BC for couple of versions. */
        "above-the-fold" : function(a) { return !$.belowthefold(a, {threshold : 0}); },
        "right-of-fold"  : function(a) { return $.rightoffold(a, {threshold : 0}); },
        "left-of-fold"   : function(a) { return !$.rightoffold(a, {threshold : 0}); }
    });

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

sorry for my bad English regards!